# My Rails Javascript manifest file neither compiles nor include any required files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I've seen a few posts similar to this but with no solutions, so I figured I would present a more documented problem.

**My Problem** JS from manifest file is not including or compiling any JS.

When running my server locally, and opening the JS file I see nothing compiled, just the standard application.js manifest file :

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require underscore
//= require backbone
//= require backbone_rails_sync
//= require backbone_datalink
//= require backbone/myapp
//= require_tree .
```

My development.rb :

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false  
  config.whiny_nils = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

My application.rb :

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
end

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
end
```

My Log :

```
Started GET "/questions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-04 08:56:09 -0400
Processing by QuestionsController#index as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 204ms (Views: 16.0ms | ActiveRecord: 17.4ms)

Started GET "/assets/application.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-04 08:56:09 -0400
Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (2ms)

Started GET "/assets/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-04 08:56:09 -0400
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Started GET "/assets/favicon.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-04 08:56:09 -0400
Served asset /favicon.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
```

**To note** , this app was cherry picked from another app as I migrated from a MongoDB build to a Postgres build. So I think that very likely, this has something to do with some *uncherrypicked* detail.

This issue can be reproduced by doing ..

1. `$ rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p0`
2. `$ rails new project`
3. Create a javascript file with `alert('hey')` in it in `/assets/javascripts/`
4. `$ rails s`

I think this issue is because Ruby 2 does not work with Rails yet :(

---

I have this officially pinpointed as Ruby 2 in incompatible with Rails 3.2.6

Comment: What's in the truncated section of the `application.js` file?

Comment: Silly question, but do you have an assets section in the gemfile with sass-rails, jquery-rails and jquery-ui-rails? I wonder if it's failing when finding dependencies. Although, the server wouldn't start with those in the manifest and the gems not installed.

Comment: I do have those gems in my assets group. I also have tried jquery-rails and backbone outside of that assets group and it works on a separate project.

Answer (score 5):

Rajesh's solution did work for me too.
I was using 2.0.0-p195 and rake assets:precompile on production didn't really read application.js and I ended up having the file application-###.js with the size of 1kb.

So I went back to ruby 1.9.3, updated the bundle, cleared the cache manually by

```
rm -rf tmp/cache/assets/*
rm -rf tmp/cache/sass/*
```

and then

in my application.js, I have

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

note that I don't use jquery-ui or jquery_ujs

then I ran

```
rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUP=assets assets:clean
rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUP=assets assets:precompile
```

Now it works.

Comment: Many give this solution of rolling back to Ruby 1.9, but it is not possible for those that use Rails 5, as it requires Ruby 2.2.2.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, took long time to find a solutions to this.

I just switched back to `ruby-1.9.3-p429`, and it resolved the problem. I don't know how to manage it with `ruby 2 patches`. I have used `ruby-2.0.0-p247` and `ruby-2.0.0-p195`.

So, just do `rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p429`. Then run 'bundle update'. Then clear the Rails cache by running `Rails.cache.clear` in the console and also don't forget to clear the browser cache.

Hope it goes fine. :)-