# Bootstrap Carousel (How to load the javascript?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm attempting to implement a bootstrap carousel. It won't slide for some reason... Whever I click on the arrow to slide my `http://localhost:3000/` goes to `http://localhost:3000/#carousel-example-generic`

I believe I am missing the necessary javascript requirements but unsure of how to include them.

In what file do they go? `application.js` or `application.css.scss` or in one of my `views`?

Also what is the code needed to be included, does it have to go in a specific place in a page? Is it `bootstrap.js`or `bootstrap-transition.js` or what else? I am really lost.

This is my carousel, I believe it is correct:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item active">
      <%= link_to image_tag("closeup.jpg", alt: "image", class:'img-responsive') %>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <%= link_to image_tag("parksolar.jpg", alt: "image", class:'img-responsive') %>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <%= link_to image_tag("big1.jpg", alt: "image", class:'img-responsive') %>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

This is my apllication.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
// bootstrap.js
// Loads all Bootstrap javascripts
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

This is my application.css.scss (note that I also have a navbar, could the sass mark up be affecting my carousel slider?)

```
@import "bootstrap";

.navbar {
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f0ad4e;
    padding-left: 150px;
    padding-right: 150px;
    padding-top: 35px;
    margin: 0px;
    background:transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: white;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: white;
}






/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 * 
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Using inspect element I found these errors:

[image]

what do they mean?

Comment: Use chrome inspector (f12) and go to the network tab, check that all your files are being loaded, if not check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811889/my-rails-javascript-manifest-file-neither-compiles-nor-include-any-required-file ,it might help

Comment: The files are being loaded

Comment: The link you provided has no answer. I am using rails 4.

Comment: I would just simply like to know what line of code to put where to include javascript?

Comment: Sry didn't check the version of your tag. But checking at your screenshot is easy to know whats wrong, you have js files with hard dependency on jquery, so jQuery must be loaded first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to share that I had solved a lot of problems of 'Javascript not working' simply by having the

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

above

```
//= require bootstrap
```

in the Application.js file.

do try this and let me know if it helps.
And can you please share your GEM file contents here?

Comment: This worked! You are a genius! Why is this necessary?

Comment: It should be above all files that have hard dependency on jQuery, not only bootstrap. Those files are trying to use jQuery before is even loaded, that's why is necessary.Btw @Ritikesh good eye ;)

Comment: haha thanks! @Zarich. And you were spot on with your explanation too! :)

Comment: Can somebody link to a documentation or something that explains this behaviour. I would be greatly insterested on how this works!